# Setting this pointer to a structure

Tags: ida

I'm reversing a program, and slowly I'm starting to build a custom structure which no doubtfully represent a class (e.g. first DWORD points a a vtable, etc.).

This is a Windows binary with some COM implementation. Some methods use the stdcall calling convention (this call on the stack), some method use the this call calling convention (this pointer on ECX).

I'd like to tell IDA that the this pointer (either on ECX or on the stack) points to my custom structure I've analyzed, so in the code view I'll see reference to the field of the class. Possible?

Answer (score 1):

The effective way to analyze virtual function table based program is to change types using ida hexray addon. The steps could be:

1. Convert the insterested function to poseduo C code .
   The hexray plugin will mark this pointer as a DWORD*/int* etc.
2. Change type of this pointer to the structure type you have analyzed (by pressing 'Y' on the this pointer variable)
    Then hexray will recgonize [ecx+offset] to Yourtype->member

But the hexray addon is very expansive.